# Installation error in Blueprism after Admin credentials are filled

Tags: debugging, installation, blueprism, rpa

I am trying to install trail version in my system. Just after I set Admin Credentials. I get the following error.
Installation Issue

[image]

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at BluePrism.AutomateAppCore.LocalDatabaseInstaller.get_a()
at BluePrism.AutomateAppCore.LocalDatabaseInstaller.get_DatabaseExists()
at AutomateUI.WelcomeWizard.h(Object iir, DoWorkEventArgs iis)
```

Can you help me find this solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have the pre requisites on your laptop:

> Blue Prism will require a remote SQL Server database or a local SQL
>   Express database to have been installed. The user will require
>   privileges within the database to create databases.
>
> If you are
>   installing an SQL Express database to support the training please
>   accept the default authentication method (Windows Authentication) and
>   default instance name (SQLExpress). If you specified SQL
>   Authentication please make sure you have an ID and password with
>   privileges to create a database.

Source: [installation guide](https://www.coursehero.com/file/p1cc0rps/This-document-provides-guidance-on-the-process-to-follow-when-carrying-out-an/)